# href does not work when i select tab

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
<ul id="shortcuts">
    <li class='current'><a href="<?=base_url()?>home" id="home">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="<?=base_url()?>message"  id='message'>Messages</a></li>

</ul>

<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shortcuts li').click(function(e){
         $('#shortcuts li').removeClass('current');
         $(this).addClass('current');
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});

</script>
```

the problem is that i want to highlight tab which is selected it is done bt when click on this tab it dont go to next page mean href does not work.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` might be preventing it

Comment: Remove `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Please show your HTML code. You're not setting any hidden divs to display here, so it could be related to `e.preventDefault()`. Also, please avoid using PHP short tags.

Comment: did you check what href value looks like? for example in source code.

Comment: Why do you use <a> tag?

Comment: if i remove e.preventDefault(); then selected tab dont highlight

Comment: <a> tag is using because it will use to go to next page

Comment: href works when i dont use jqury for highlighting selected tab

Comment: it also highlight on mouseover but i also whant that  when the link is clicked i want to go to that page, then when reaching that page i want to highlight the current page in the menu

Comment: it is best to put all code to jsFiddle,and show here. Then it will be more clear what is the problem. Without it we dont know how your tabs work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're wanting the page not to change when a link is clicked, but you want the style of the list item changed instead. This should do the trick:

```
$('#shortcuts li a').click(function(e){
     // Prevent the link from changing the page
     e.preventDefault();

     // Remove 'current' from any list item with the 'current' class
     $('#shortcuts li.current').removeClass('current');

     // Add the 'current' class to the link's parent (its list item container)
     $(this).parent().addClass('current');
});
```

What you currently have is telling the browser to not perform any default action when the list item is clicked, but not when the link itself is clicked, making it not work.

Comment: i got impression he want page to be changed.

Comment: no i  wants  the page also change when a link is clicked, also want the style of the list item changed

Comment: Clicking a link causes the page to change. When a page has changed the script from the previous page can't affect the new page. To do this in JavaScript you'd need to determine which page you're on based on the URL and add the class to the appropriate list item. To do this in PHP you could use $_SESSION to pass the ID of the required list item over into the next page.

Comment: someone told me to use window.location.pathname for this purpose bt i dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether short open tags are allowed in your server.
Its very basic, but, please look into it.

In php.ini, there is one directive:

short_open_tags

For your script, it must be on.
Please check for it.

Answer (score 0):

May be it help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shortcuts li a').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#shortcuts li').removeClass('current');
         $(this).parent().addClass('current');
         return false;
    });
});
```